# Personal Info In Commercial Video

Tags: internet, employment, business, privacy, liability

If my phone number is put in a commercial video for sale (in a scene involving texting) without my authorization is that illegal? What action can be taken? I work on the set, I've never signed a release, I went to my boss and she did nothing, the film was released and is being sold, I had someone (a fan) text me to see if the number is real trying to see if it was the actors phone number.

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: @phoog I live in MA and the video shoots are in MA/NH. I'm not sure where her company is technically base out of but the company that releases her films is in Canada.

Comment: You ought to talk to a lawyer; probably one with experience in the entertainment industry.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to consulting an attorney you might also consider sending a strongly worded letter or email. Outline the facts and ask them to stop using your number immediately as you did not authorize it. You might mention that if you don't receive a written promise (at minimum) from them within, say, 48 hours you will have no choice but to hire an attorney and you might seek to collect damages, attorneys fees and all other legal remedies available to you.